# Symfony EasyAdminBundle: Dql Filter entities in assotiation field on List not worrking

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms, symfony2-easyadmin

I have a form with association field type (list of related entities).

There is Quizz entity with field entity "TypeQuizz" (@ORM\ManyToOne).
Impossible to use DQl Filter to Display List Quizz .

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Challenge\TypeQuizz")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $typeQuizz;
```

Can not display the quiz list based on the codeTypeQuizz of the TypeQuizz entity

File config EasyAdmin.yaml
[image]

Error to impossible to access property association TypeQuizz from entity Quizz with DQL Filter

[image]

How to apply Dql Filter on property association entity?

Answer (score 8):

I overwrite method createListQueryBuilder for support entities association

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller\Admin;

use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AdminController as BaseAdminController;

class QuizzChallengeController extends BaseAdminController
{
    protected function createListQueryBuilder($entityClass, $sortDirection, $sortField = null, $dqlFilter = null)
    {
        /* @var EntityManager */
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManagerForClass($this->entity['class']);
        /* @var DoctrineQueryBuilder */
        $queryBuilder = $em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('entity')
            ->from($this->entity['class'], 'entity')
            ->leftJoin('entity.typeQuizz','typeQuizz');

        if (!empty($dqlFilter)) {
            $queryBuilder->andWhere($dqlFilter);
        }

        if (null !== $sortField) {
            $queryBuilder->orderBy('entity.'.$sortField, $sortDirection ?: 'DESC');
        }

        return $queryBuilder;
    }
}
```

I modified the dql_filter in the .yml file, deleted the 'entity' and called the alias directly.
[image]

This solution works for me.